# Default save location not document library where file generated from

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepointdocumentlibrary

We're using SharePoint Online and noticed a peculiarity when creating documents from the document library's 'New' menu option.  Our document libraries have been configured with the "Open Documents in Client Applications by Default" enabled.  When we select New->Document, Word opens on the user's desktop.  Document library meta data fields are visible on the right, so I know there's some connection between the newly generated file and properties of the doc lib.  However, when press CRTL + S, my default location isn't the doc lib from which the file was instantiated, but my personal OneDrive.  If I want the file saved back to the correct document library, I need to click More Locations-> Browse and then select my original document library.   I understand Microsoft are pushing saving files back to OneDrive, but this seems like odd behaviour to me (as do the users we support).

Is there a way to make the default save location the document library from which the document was created?

Tks

Answer (score 0):

Have a try to clean your browser cache or change a browser to open your document library and retry creating a document in your library to see if it is a browser-related issue.

Comment: It doesn't matter which browser I use or multiple machines/users.  The user experience is the same no matter what.